# Chromatography types and techniques

Tags: chromatography

Are HPLC and GC comparable in term to size exclusion, ion exchange, sequential injection chromatography? Or they are two different terms, HPLC and GC refers to the equipment and phase of the analyte, while IEC, HIC, SEC are the principles that would refer more to the column itself?

Comment: These are very "googlable" questions. Maybe a good starting point for you would be to figure out what these acrynoms stand for. *Eg.* GC means gas chromatography.

Comment: You are mixing apples, oranges, airplanes and fatty acids